# Plot progressively using system pause/sleep

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I have the following piece of code, but it is not working as expected.

```
for(i in 3:nrow(pima_diabetes_kmean)){
  k.means.fit <- kmeans(pima_diabetes_kmean[1:i, c("Pregnancy", "Age")], 2)
  plot(
    pima_diabetes_kmean[1:i, c("Pregnancy", "Age")],
    col = alpha(k.means.fit$cluster, 0.2),
    pch = 20,
    cex = 3, main = "Clusters predicted by models"
  )
  points(
    k.means.fit$centers,
    pch = 4,
    cex = 4,
    lwd = 4,
    col = "blue"
  )
  Sys.sleep(0.001)
}
```

I can remove the loop and plot it all at once. But instead I want to plot first 3 rows of data, then 4 rows after a gap of 0.001s, then 5, and so on. It will eventually plot all the data points.

I want to capture the process, so that I can create a video or gif showing how the addition of each point affects the clusterization. But this plot is plotting it all at once, instead of stepwise, as if the for loop is non-existent.

Comment: If you  want to produce animated plots, look at the `animation` package: it might require you to restructure your code a bit, but will make producing a video at the end much easier.

Comment: 0.001 seconds is very short! Maybe increase this to 0.1s

Comment: Yeah, it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it worked:

```
png(file="kMeanPlot%03d.png", width=719, height=539)
for(i in seq(3, nrow(pima_diabetes_kmean), by = 20)){
  k.means.fit <- kmeans(pima_diabetes_kmean[1:i, c("Pregnancy", "Age")], 2)
  plot(
    pima_diabetes_kmean[1:i, c("Pregnancy", "Age")],
    col = alpha(k.means.fit$cluster, 0.2),
    pch = 20,
    cex = 3, main = "Clusters predicted by models"
  )
  points(
    k.means.fit$centers,
    pch = 4,
    cex = 4,
    lwd = 4,
    col = "blue"
  )
}
dev.off()

# convert the .png files to one .gif file using ImageMagick. 
# The system()/shell() function executes the command as if it was done
# in the terminal. the -delay flag sets the time between showing
# the frames, i.e. the speed of the animation.
# You will need to install the imagemagick for this
# Following command for non-windows OS
# system("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.5-Q16/convert -delay 80 *.png fucked.gif") 
# Following command for Windows OS
shell("convert -delay 40 *.png kMeanPlot.gif")

# to not leave the directory with the single png files I remove them.
file.remove(list.files(pattern="[kMeanPlot]*.png"))
```